# Unable to open spreadsheet using gspread with error: KeyError: 'access_token'

Tags: python, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, gspread

I've been following this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E&list=PLdu6wGxXWFgX9XlahY9gHEMdZ7CL5CHMY&index=6) tutorial on using the google sheets API in python recently but have been met with the following error:

```
C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jadot/PycharmProjects/multiplicationTable/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 196, in jwt_grant
    access_token = response_data["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    sheet = client.open("multiplicationTable").sheet1
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 122, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files(title),
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 99, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 64, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 476, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 410, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
  File "C:\Users\jadot\PycharmProjects\multiplicationTable\venv\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 199, in jwt_grant
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ0ZTA2Y2ViMjJiMDFiZTU2YzIxM2M5ODU0MGFiNTYzYmZmNWE1OGMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.TEjhypfcTum53KYhiQkrRSCXAOna2poZAAGMUorMJiXP6en89ETDRrcrbxYHX6FMKTmWANyG-H9Fg3xUq6FnB-uLQQkRmEgw0r2K6meCJa97sPhoU0khRAwvbLesMFLO8mOBMJ7NzJythmdi8XFMc9LajthtkUZ4Ko_QfHBdPMK9iv90qAPyrmQsl1rTh6yycfvYrUFExpogsBc0Ax3vfwyjohiywQ3YenQBmgNYuE7QBtUvVgG_yGkDZI40QBK9nO_oJqDhvO_QhsH-42g5X26dBDkerWzZ0DikGTeMgPCFSGBmv0Cd2rKyLQL5JcYJNHEKAHgVVs__SFB_OWha3Q'})

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("C:/Users/jadot/PycharmProjects/multiplicationTable/creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("multiplicationTable").sheet1
```

There are several similar cases on stack overflow, all of which I've tried with no avail.